# passing multi value parameter to SSRS report from SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am triggering SSRS report from SSIS(Script task). I am passing parameter values from SSIS package.

So far working fine. Now, I have a report which has 2 parameters. One is single value parameter and the other is multi value parameter.

No issue assigning value to single value parameter. But how can I pass multi value to multi value parameter?

My code as below

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService()
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
rs.Url = _webserviceURL;
rs.LoadReport(_reportPath, null);

ParameterValue[] paramval = new ParameterValue[2];
paramval[0] = new ParameterValue();
paramval[0].Name = "CountryCode";
paramval[0].Value = _countryNames;

paramval[1] = new ParameterValue();
paramval[1].Name = "BusinessCode";
paramval[1].Value = _businessCode;

rs.SetExecutionParameters(paramval, "en-us");
```

I am not sure how to pass value to BusinessCode(Multi value parameter)

Comment: I don't know about calling SSRS from SSIS. But when using a Multi valued parameter from within SSRS it's just a comma seperated list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use List to pass multiple parameter like - `List<RSExec.ParameterValue> lstParameterValues = new List<RSExec.ParameterValue>();` and then iterate list

```
    RSExec.ParameterValue aParameter = new RSExec.ParameterValue();
aParameter.Name = "Year";
aParameter.Label = "";
aParameter.Value = "2010";
lstParameterValues.Add(aParameter);

RSExec.ParameterValue aParameter = new RSExec.ParameterValue();
aParameter.Name = "Year";
aParameter.Label = "";
aParameter.Value = "2011";
lstParameterValues.Add(aParameter);

int index = 0;
RSExec.ParameterValue[] parameterValues = new RSExec.ParameterValue[lstParameterValues.Count];
foreach (RSExec.ParameterValue parameterValue in lstParameterValues)
{
  parameterValues[index] = parameterValue;
  index++;
}
```

and then Call `SetExecutionParameters` with that array

Below article has code sample to accomplish same.

[Running Multi-Value SSRS Reports from C#](http://technicalreflections.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/running-multi-value-ssrs-reports-from-c/)

Comment: TL;DR: You have to create multiple ParameterValue objects with the same "Name" property and add them to the array. Thanks for the article :)